# kube proxy issue with connection issue on master node

Tags: kubernetes

Getting following issue in kube proxy running on master Node

```
.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1114 19:39:37.146635 1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:49: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get https://10.196.12.154:6443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.196.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1114 19:39:37.147411 1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:46: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://10.196.12.154:6443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.196.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1114 19:39:38.156190 1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:49: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get https://10.196.12.154:6443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.196.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1114 19:39:38.156820 1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy/config/api.go:46: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://10.196.12.154:6443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.196.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
E1114 19:39:39.156977 1 reflector.go:201] 



Environment:

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4+1a3f593", GitCommit:"1a3f593cf0182255938f48eb2e68110c4c049c54", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-02T18:32:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4+59f69d2", GitCommit:"59f69d284801d7df9639d83f4407cad73ea467be", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-24T23:56:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: How did you setup cluster? kubeadm?

Comment: Kube api-server is having problem

Comment: This might just be iptables issue.

Try adding `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` to master and worker nodes.

Comment: Yes i used kubeadm to setup cluster  .@vjdhama iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT already added

Comment: is your kube-dns pod running? can you please post log of kube-dns pod?

Answer (score 0):

based on the error message, its not able to connect to API server, Do you have any other firewall in between? also check and see api server binded to all the network interface `ss -tnlp |grep 6443`

> tcp 10.196.12.154:6443: getsockopt: connection refused